# Orientation of negative polarity notation in voltage source when connected horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

This question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176296/18678) but I could not get the satisfactory output. My MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}

%%% Independent voltage source - American style
%\makeatletter
%\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{%
%   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
%    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
%    \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \pgfscope
%        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
%        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
%        \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \endpgfscope
%    \pgfscope
%        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
%        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
%        \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \endpgfscope
%}
%\makeatother
%
%%% Controlled voltage source - American
%
%\makeatletter
%\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{cvsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/width}}{
%
%    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
%
%      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
%        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
%        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%        %\pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{$+$}
%        %\pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{$-$}
%        \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \pgfscope
%        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
%        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
%        \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \endpgfscope
%    \pgfscope
%        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
%        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
%        \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \endpgfscope
%}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.22cm,y=3.22cm]
\node[](a)at(0,0){};
\draw ($(a)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  to [V, l=1<\volt>] ($(a)+(0.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{} 
    to [V, l_=2<\volt>] ($(a)+(1.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output of the code is shown below in which we see that the negative polarity of 2V source is **vertically marked** *instead of horizontal mark*:

[image: output of the original code]

Now, if we uncomment the codes provided in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176463/18678) of the aforementioned question, we get the output which is not properly displayed as

[image: output of the modified code]

**Is there a way to get the output like this with proper orientation of the negative polarity?**
[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this just amount to switching `+` and `-` in the code that you commented out, and to perhaps reduce the shifts?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}

%% Independent voltage source - American style
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
   \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
   \pgfusepath{draw}
   \pgfscope
       \pgftransformxshift{0.8*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
       \pgfusepath{draw}
   \endpgfscope
   \pgfscope
       \pgftransformxshift{0.8*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
       \pgfusepath{draw}
   \endpgfscope
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.22cm,y=3.22cm]
\node[](a)at(0,0){};
\draw ($(a)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  to [V, l=1<\volt>] ($(a)+(0.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{} 
    to [V, l_=2<\volt>] ($(a)+(1.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry it didn't strike in my mind. It works!

Comment: I have added a follow up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453356/18678). Please check and provide me suitable changes