# Orientation of negative polarity notation in voltage source when connected diagonally

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

**Follow up** of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453285/18678) question. MWE is give below:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}
%
%%% Independent voltage source - American style :: rotate polarity
%\makeatletter
%\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{%
%   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
%   \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
%       {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
%   \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \pgfscope
%       \pgftransformxshift{0.7*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
%       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
%       \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \endpgfscope
%   \pgfscope
%       \pgftransformxshift{0.7*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
%       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
%       \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \endpgfscope
%}
%\makeatother
%
%%% Controlled voltage source - American style :: rotate polarity
%
%\makeatletter
%\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{cvsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/width}}{%
%   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
%   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
%   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
%   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
%   \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \pgfscope
%       \pgftransformxshift{0.7*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
%       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
%       \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \endpgfscope
%   \pgfscope
%       \pgftransformxshift{0.7*\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
%       \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
%       \pgfusepath{draw}
%   \endpgfscope
%}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.22cm,y=3.22cm]
\node[](a)at(0,0){};
\draw ($(a)+(0.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{}  to [cV, l=1<\volt>] ($(a)+(0.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{} 
    to [V, l_=2<\volt>] ($(a)+(1.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{} 
    to [cV, l_=3<\volt>] ($(a)+(2.0,1.0)$) node[circ]{} 
    to [V, l=4<\volt>, label/align=straight] ($(a)+(1.0,0.0)$) node[circ]{};
\draw ($(a)+(0.0,1.0)$) to [cV, l=1<\volt>, label/align=straight] ($(a)+(1.0,0.0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the output as

[image: default output of tikz+circuitikz]

when uncommented the codes in the above MWE, the output is:

[image: modified the polarity notation for horizontal display]

however, I am looking for something like this below for diagonally connected voltage sources as well:

[image: desired output]

***Any suggestion please?***

Comment: I don't know tikz, but looks like a little bit different `rotate` angle, have a look at the `rotate` calls in the answer of your precious question.

Comment: @albert, actually that `rotate` helps in rotating the polarity in horizontal display. Acually, I am at a lost for diagonal rotation. If `-` notation is removed, the -ve sign on diagonal voltage source becomes vertical which is undesirable in fact

Comment: @albert, diagonal is fixed with `\pgftext[rotate=-0.28*\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}` however, source in perpendicular display like 1V source has a problem

Comment: The modification was specifically to ALWAYS draw the symbols right side up. Trying to guess the most esthetically pleasing angle is a much harder question.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, true. With my limited knowledge in tikz-pgf, trying to get a book like circuit diagram display becomes impossible

Comment: What about other angles then 45^\circ?  Easiest would be to add a new parameter for the desired angle on a node by node basis.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Modification to the default orientation so far originates from your [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176463/18678) however you didn't address the diagonal display there too. I am still unable to modify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a new variable `bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation/.initial=0` and then insert it in the component redefinition for `vsourceAM` and `cvsourceAM` in the code for the minus sign to rotate the text using `rotatebox:`

```
... \pgftext[options]{\rotatebox{bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation}{$-$}}
```

to enable the option to rotate the minus changing the value to 90 degrees inside the component defintition:

```
...
to [V,l_=$2V$,-*,bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation=90] 
...
```

Here a MWE using the defined sintax for circuitikz and with relative coordinates `++(x_shift,y_shift)`, in this case depending of the value of `\dist`, setted out to `4cm` to get better presentation using `bipoles/length=2cm`, remark that to draw the shorts the notation `*-`, `-*`, `*-*` is used instead drawing circles; to change the size the value to change is: `nodes width/.initial=0.03`.

RESULT: The 2V diagonal cotrolled source has sign modification and the 4V diagonal independient source is in the default value 0. you can choose what has better look.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
%% Independent voltage source - American style
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation/.initial=0}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{$+$}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{$-$}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\rotatebox{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation}}{$-$}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{$+$}
    \fi
}

%% Controlled voltage source - American
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{cvsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/width}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{$+$}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{$-$}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\rotatebox{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation}}{$-$}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{$+$}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=2cm}
\ctikzset{nodes width/.initial=0.03}
\def\dist{4}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
    (0,0)
        to [cV,l=$1V$,*-*] ++(0,\dist) coordinate (div-01)
        to [V,l_=$2V$,-*,bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation=90] ++ (\dist,0)
        to [cV,l_=$3V$,-*,bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation=90] ++ (\dist,0)
        to [V,l=$4V$,-*] ++ (-\dist,-\dist)
    (div-01)
        to [cV,l_=$2V$,-*,bipoles/vsources/minus/sign/rotation=90] ++ (\dist,-\dist);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```